# Upload and save pdf as template using docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to upload and create a Template using Docusign api. I tried sending post request in {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/templates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to create a Template by using the DocuSign API. For details, see this [DocuSign API documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about `PDF`s.